# postfix virtual domain, users, aliases, and procmail

Tags: postfix-mta, procmail

I have had a virtual postfix/dovecot/procmail server set up for some time, and for the most part everything is working fine. The only quirk that I can’t figure out is some virtual aliases seem to fall through to the virtual domain’s catchall mailbox rather than getting delivered to the intended virtual user. Not sure if it’s my postfix or procmail settings.

I've included below what I think is the relevant parts of the relevant config files. If you need more, let me know.

What's happening is that mail getting sent to troy@example2.com.au gets correctly delivered to /var/mail/vhosts/example2.com.au/troy
But mail sent to one of the aliases like info@example2.com.au does not go to /var/mail/vhosts/example2.com.au/troy but rather /var/mail/vhosts

What am I missing?

```
### /etc/postfix/main.cf extract ####
mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail -a "${EXTENSION}"
home_mailbox = Maildir/
mydestination = dove.example1.local, dove, dove.example1.com, localhost.localdomain, localhost, example1.dyndns.org
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 192.168.0.0/22 
inet_interfaces = all 
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases 
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases 
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport 
relay_domains = $mydestination

virtual_mailbox_domains = example1.com example2.com.au 
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/mail/vhosts 
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmailbox 
virtual_minimum_uid = 100 
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000 
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000 
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual

virtual_transport = procmail
procmail_destination_recipient_limit = 1 
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport 
########################

### /etc/postfix/vmailbox extract ####
troy@example2.com.au example2.com.au/troy/
info@example2.com.au example2.com.au/troy/
accounts@example2.com.au example2.com.au/troy/
linkedin@example2.com.au example2.com.au/troy/
facebook@example2.com.au example2.com.au/troy/
office@example2.com.au example2.com.au/troy/
sysadmin@example2.com.au example2.com.au/troy/
webmaster@example2.com.au example2.com.au/troy/

dc@example2.com.au example2.com.au/jeevan/
jeevan@example2.com.au example2.com.au/jeevan/ 
########################

### /etc/postfix/transport extract ####
example1.com procmail
example2.com.au procmail
########################

### /etc/postfix/master.cf extract ####
procmail unix - n n - - pipe
flags=DROhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/procmail -t -m USER=${user}
EXTENSION=${extension} NEXTHOP=${nexthop} /etc/postfix/procmailrc.common 
########################

### /etc/postfix/procmailrc.common extract #### 
MAILDIR=${HOME}/${NEXTHOP}/${USER}
DEFAULT=${MAILDIR}/
########################
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TBH, I don't know why this does not work, it looks fine to me. But you may try using a VirtualAlias to redirect `info@example2.com.au` to `troy@example2.com.au`.

Also, you should head over to [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) with that question - it's rather off-topic here.

Comment: Apologies if I posted this in the wrong forum.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: BTW I'm pretty sure that virtual aliases must point to either a local system account (and I think that means not virtual) or a remote address.  But I'll get that confirmed at the appropriate place.

Comment: No, they don'T have to. I have quite a lot that redirect to other addresses, that's perfectly valid (it might only work if the domain is a VirtualDOmain though)

Comment: Aah.  Excellent.  Just added "alias1@example1.com troy@example1.com" to the virtual alias maps file, and removed the "alias1..." line from the virtual mailbox maps file and it does work!  Thanks mate!  That's been bugging me for months!